# "sudo npm install -g ionic" shows nothing

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I'm trying to install ionic in my ubuntu laptop. 
I have successfully installed Node.js and Cordova. They are working properly.
But when I try to install Ionic from *sudo npm install -g ionic* it doesn't give any output. 
Then I wrote *ionic* in cmd, it says *No command 'ionic' found,*
Any idea about this is really appreciated.

[cmd outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY7ZI.png)

Comment: try typing `npm -v` and see the output?

Comment: It gives *4.2.0*

Comment: Are other globally installed modules working?

Comment: yes, I installed cordova globally and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Your npm is not correctly installed. Try to uninstall it and install again.